# MacBookPro External Ubuntu Boot issue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, mac

On my Mac, I wanted the option to boot to Ubuntu from a SD card (64gb), so I used syslinux/unebootin to make an Ubuntu 16.04.2 live USB. Booted into that successfully and installed Ubuntu on the SD card, having a 4gb swap, the rest to the os, and the bootloader also on the SD card. (Upon rebooting, only the SD card was plugged in [not live USB]) I then booted back into OSx (Ubuntu did not come up, nor a bootloader but I feel like that's expected) so I installed rEFInd. Rebooted to be greeted by the EFI screen, the options being to boot Ubuntu from grub and the standard boot Mac.

Now, when I selected the Ubuntu option, it brought me right to the grub prompt (not recovery). After a quick Google I punched in `ls` to which I saw the two hd entries, but hd0 was just that, hd1 having a few other `(hd1,*something*)`. After that, it gave the following message: `failure reading sector 0x0 from hd0`. After not finding anything specific about it via some searches, I decided to move on and try some other stuff.

On a whim, I decided to boot into the Live USB (using the `alt` key on startup), which brought me to the normal Live environment. Restarted into the USB again to check the other options, when I hit `esc`. This brought me to another grub menu, but this one was fullscreen with correctly-sized text (other one was just in the middle of the screen). Here, there was no issue from `ls`. The SD card was listed and its contents matched that of what should be on an Ubuntu drive. I then typed `exit` and the unthinkable happened: it booted into Ubuntu correctly! I installed a few drivers/tweaked some settings to test persistence (more of a curiosity) and was satisfied. Then I tried to install rEFInd via there, which created an entry (when booting via rEFInd without the Live USB) for Ubuntu which brings me to MokManager (and as far as I can tell, that deals with Windows Safe Boot?).

So, from where I am, it seems that the only way for me to boot into my Ubuntu SD card is to have the Live USB in, boot to that, and then exit grub. How can I fix this so I won't need the Live USB and only the SD card?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had installed Ubuntu correctly to your SD card, then you have to preform the following steps in macOS to finish the installation. Here, I assume 64 bit version of Ubuntu was installed to use the EFI boot method.

The steps below copy the boot file for grub to the correct location in the EFI partition. This is not only a requirement for the Mac Startup Manager, but is also defined in the UEFI specification.

1. Enter the command `diskutil list` to determine the identifier of the EFI partition on your SD card. In the steps given below, this identifier is assumed to be `disk1s1`. If you determined a difference identifier, then make the appropriate substitutions.
2. From a Terminal application window, enter the command `diskutil mount disk1s1`. A new device representing this partition should appear in the Finder application.
3. Using the Finder application, navigate to this device.
4. Create a folder labeled `boot` in the folder `EFI`.
5. Copy the file `grubx64.efi` found in the `EFI/ubuntu` folder to the `EFI/boot` folder.
6. Rename the  `grubx64.efi` file in the `EFI/boot` folder to `bootx64.efi`.
7. From a Terminal application window, enter the command `diskutil unmount disk1s1`.

If you can boot to the correctly installed Ubuntu operating system, then the above steps can be replaced by commands given below. These commands need to be entered in a Ubuntu Terminal window.

> Note: To enter these commands, you will have to know the root users password.

```
su
mkdir  /boot/efi/efi/boot
cp  /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi  /boot/efi/efi/boot/bootx64.efi
exit
```

Once the changes are made, you can do the following to choose an operating system.

1. Start or restart your Mac and immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager appears.
2. Select the icon for the desired operating system. Ubuntu will appear with label `EFI Boot`.
3. To boot the desired operating system, select the arrow below the chosen icon .

   > Note: If you hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key while selecting the arrow, the chosen operating system will be come the default.